# how to get all checked checkboxes from a dynamically generated form in the order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have written a code which retrives all values of elements within a form its working with radio button, text boxes , dropdown , text area .but now i want to add checkboxes the problem is with checkboxes we can have multiple values for a particular name,so need to get the checkboxes values in order as they apper in the form

Here is the code to get the values:

```
var elements="";
                var $this = jQuery(this);
                $this.parents(".detailTable").find(":input").each(function(index, elm){
                if((jQuery(this).attr("type")=="button") ||(jQuery(this).attr("type")=="hidden"))
                {
                }else if((jQuery(this).attr("type")=="radio")){
                    if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){
                    elements=elements + (jQuery(this).val());
                    elements=elements + "|";
            //      alert(jQuery(this).val())
                    }
                }else if((jQuery(this).attr("type")=="checkbox")){
                    if(jQuery(this).attr("checked")){
                    elements=elements + (jQuery(this).val());
                    elements=elements + "|";
                }
                }
                else{
                    elements=elements + (jQuery(this).val());
                    elements=elements + "|";
                //  alert(jQuery(this).val());
                }
                });
```

I want all the values of a checkbox group comma seperated(form can have multiple checkboxes) while between elements the values are '|' seprated.

Can you help me with this

Comment: Have you seen jQuery's _.serialize()_ (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method?  I'd start there, then create your encoded string from the returned data object.

Comment: @MattStone i dont want the hidden and submit elemetns so i cant use serialize elements

Answer (score 0):

try using the `.map()` method..

```
var checkedBoxes= $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
                     return this.value ;
                  }).get().join('|');
```

Comment: but i want the elements in order as they have to be stored in the D/B in the order which they appear in the form

Comment: You can use $(":input").serializeArray();

Comment: But this will not make sure you are only sending checked items

Comment: yes for the radio button and checkbox i only want the checked vlaues to be stored in db .and in case of checkboxes the values will be comma seperated

Comment: what you mean by "this will not make sure you are only sending checked items"

Comment: you can use $(":input").serializeArray();  but it will send all the input types whether checked or not .. If you want them in a sequential order